# MySQL: Get one row for each item in the IN clause efficiently

Tags: mysql, limit, where-clause

I have a MySQL database with a lot of tables, and I have two tables that are linked to each other in a many to many relationship, using a third table. Here's a simplified demonstration of how it looks like:

Table 1: books

- Row 1: ID: 15 Title: Dummy Testbook 1
- Row 2: ID: 18 Title: Dummy Testbook 4
- Row 3: ID: 22 Title: Dummy Testbook 6
- Row 4: ID: 10 Title: Dummy Testbook 8
- Row 5: ID: 16 Title: Dummy Testbook 15
- ...

Table 2: authors

- Row 1: ID: 4 Name: Dave
- Row 2: ID: 8 Name: Robert
- Row 3: ID: 12 Name: Amy

Table 3: books_authors

Row 1: author_id: 4  book_id: 15

Row 1: author_id: 8  book_id: 22

Row 1: author_id: 8  book_id: 10

Row 1: author_id: 12  book_id: 16

What I am trying to do is to get a random list of authors with the latest book per each author, so I am getting a list with all author ids, using some scripting to create that random list, and then I am using the following query:

```
SELECT 
`books`.`ID`, 
`books`.`Name` 
FROM `books` 
  LEFT JOIN `books_authors` ON `books`.`ID` = `books_authors`.`book_id`
  LEFT JOIN `authors` ON `books_authors`.`author_id` = `authors`.`ID` 
WHERE  `authors`.`ID` IN(8, 12) 
LIMIT 1
```

The problem is, the Limit 1 means that I will only get one book, while I want to get two books, one per each author. How can I do that without running a query for each author? (the database is huge, and a query for each author will bring the server to a crawl). If I increase the limit, then I am not necessarily getting two books one per each other, but I may get two books by the same author.

In other words, I want the limit to be on the IN, not on the entire query. Is that possible? and if not, is there an efficient way of doing what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Which exact "one book" you need for each author? The latest one? Any one? Btw, you not need `LEFT JOIN`, use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: "a query for each author will bring the server to a crawl" So then hire a DBA.

Comment: When you say "latest" book, do you mean `max(book_id)`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem without a join.....$result = mysql_query("SELECT total FROM table1 WHERE client='$client' and campaign IN ('Car', 'Van', 'Bike', 'Bus') ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first select the for each author books with the latest id and join it with books table to get names. Something like that:

```
SELECT 
`books`.`ID`, 
`books`.`Name` 
FROM `books`
  INNER JOIN (
    select max(book_id), author_id
    from `books_authors`
    group by author_id) ba ON `books`.`ID` = ba.`book_id`
WHERE ba.author_id IN (8, 12)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of solutions to this problem [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), but the gist of it is that if your dataset is huge, you are probably best off running multiple queries, one per author.

Comment: Yes, the latest book. Or Max(book id)

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the answer for this question but it worked for me for similar problem.

I have a resultset from a query with columns A, B, C, D, E. As I want one line for any D+E-type result (I don't care wich one), I've done that with a "group by D,E" function.

35.000+ registers, each column was varchar(30), Mysql take 766 ms to do that work.