# Mysql query picking highest ID using "WHERE IN" and LIMIT, not returning enough results

Tags: php, mysql

PROBLEM: 
This query will only show the correct answer if I change the LIMIT to however how many results are in my IN statement.

AIM: - I want the amount in my variable(Car,Van,Bike,Bus) to equal the amount on the limit.

My IN statement is actually a variable that changes and can have from 1-50 items (truck, taxi etc), but for ease I have used 4. If it has 3 items them I have to change the LIMIT to 3 and so on.

I could do a query, then explode into array, and count items the use this number as a variable to add to the limit, but that's 2 queries!

*Easy to read query: -*

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT total FROM table1 WHERE client='$client'
and campaign IN ('Car', 'Van', 'Bike', 'Bus') ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");
```

The car,van,bike and bus come from a database query themselves....

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT rules FROM combined WHERE groupname='$groupname'");
```

This produced **'Car', 'Van', 'Bike', 'Bus'**

*Mock data*: - 
Car = 1,
Van = 2,
Bike = 3,
Bus = 4.

Answer on this query is 1+2+3+4
But if I had a rule where there were 5 in the campaign IN part it would be the same, as it is only fetching 4 answers not 5.
So its still only adding 1+2+3+4, as the limit is 4 not now 5.

The bold parts are actually stored in the database with slashes added.
$rule = **'Car', 'Van', 'Bike', 'Bus'**;

The real mysql statement is below: -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT total FROM table1 WHERE client='$client' 
and campaign IN ($rule) ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");
```

=======================================================================
Explanation

The following query gets me this data ('Car', 'Van', 'Bike', 'Bus')

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT rules FROM combined WHERE groupname='$groupname'");
```

I place this in a variable called $rule

I then run this query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT total FROM table1 WHERE client='$client'
and campaign IN ($rule) ORDER BY id DESC limit 4");
```

This will return a number for each of these (total for Car = 1, total for Van = 2)

Problem is that when there is more than 4 in my $rule it wont return more than 4 because of the limit. I would have to change it everytime.

Can I combine the two querys....and get the highest id of each of the Car,Van, Bike campaigns. (that appear in my IN statement or $rule)

Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: I don't understand what's your question. Do you want the amount of all values (then use SQL keywords MAX, SUM, MIN or COUNT) or what is your question?

Comment: When I receive 4 items in the returned results, I have a hardcoded LIMIT on it, but as the results changes so should the LIMIT. Is there a better way maybe to join both the querys together..... Kind of the same as this questions problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987529/mysql-get-one-row-for-each-item-in-the-in-clause-efficiently?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: what are you actually trying to get? what's your final goal?! I don't see why the limit is needed, we don't understand what result do you want.

Comment: Why don't you count your ""in"" query an use that result to set your limit dynamically?

Comment: sqlab asked what happens if I omit the LIMIT, In reply to sqlab, it will add up ALL of the results of that campaign (ie if there are 30 Bike campaigns, it will add them all together, not just the latest(highest ID). Need to add one of that campaign only, the latest.

Comment: This question is confusing because sql doesn't behave as you describe - add real examples of executed queries, obtained results and expected results to the question.

Comment: I think @Vatev has the solution! did you try it?

Comment: Ok @Vatev wins..... It worked for what I need.....Just a lot of testing now....Thanks to all helped..difficult to describe.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really what you need, but it answers my interpretation of the question:

```
SELECT total
FROM table1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id
    FROM table1
    WHERE campaign IN ('Car', 'Van', 'Bike', 'Bus')
    GROUP BY campaign
) t ON t.id = table1.id
```